# WebBrowser InvokeScript

Tags: c#, javascript

I have a Webrowser with some settings that are changed using javascript. I'm trying to use the example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc452443%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) but can't get the correct syntax

the script looks like this

```
        <div class="DisplayInput"><input type="radio" name="displaytype" 
value="decimal" onclick="setdisplayType('decimal');" checked="checked"><a 
    href="javaScript:setdisplayType('decimal');" 
    onclick="s_objectID=&quot;javascript:setdisplayType('decimal');_1&quot;;return this.s_oc?     this.s_oc(e):true">Decimal</a></div>
```

So far I've tried these with no success

```
this.webBrowser1.InvokeScript("setdisplayType");
this.webBrowser1.InvokeScript("setdisplayType('decimal')");
this.webBrowser1.InvokeScript("setdisplayType","decimal");
```

Comment: Where is your function setdisplayType defined? You don't show it anywhere.

Comment: What happens when you run the various `InvokeScript` calls?  Is an error thrown?  Does nothing happen?

Comment: The error shown is `Unknown name. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020006 (DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME))`. Perhaps I've misunderstood the InvokeScript functionality? I'm attempting to click a radio button on the page that's already loaded into a WPF webbrowser.

Comment: Unknown name happens when it can't find that function name. Are you sure you have that function on your page? Make sure this works for you: webBrowser1.InvokeScript("alert", "hello");

Comment: Sorry everyone, the last version does work `this.webBrowser1.InvokeScript("setdisplayType","decimal");` I used  setDisplayType instead of setdisplayType.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without knowing what's happening with your application's error and also not knowing what `setdisplayType` looks like, I'm guessing that maybe you're trying to invoke the function `setdisplayType` before it's been loaded.  Per the MSDN documentation...

> InvokeScript(String, Object()) should not be called before the
>   document that implements it has finished loading. You can detect when
>   a document has finished loading by handling the **LoadCompleted** event.

Maybe you can implement the `LoadCompleted` event handler and then invoke your script.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It is in the LoadCompleted event already so it has completed loading. I think it's just the wrong syntax I'm using to pass the function name and args.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass an array of Object as second parameter.
You can do it this way :

```
Object[] parameters = new Object[1]; //assuming your JS function has one parameter
parameters[0] = (Object)"yourStringParameter"; //for example the parameter is a string
yourBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("scriptName", parameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private async void web_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
  Object[] parameters = new Object[1]; 
  await yourBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("scriptName", parameters);
}
```