# WPF WebBrowser Control Invoke error - Unknown name. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020006 (DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME))

Tags: javascript, c#, wpf, powerbi-embedded

I am trying to embed power BI report in the WPF desktop application. I am following this blog https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/integrate-power-bi-dashboards-reports-and-tiles-into-a-wpf-application/

I am using App Owns Data and Service Principal as authentication method. I am able to get access token and the reports that are available in my powerbi workspace.

I am facing this error when invoking the javascript function from the cs file.

Here is my code :
**
ReportLoader.js**

```
/// <reference path="../powerbi.js" />

function LoadEmbeddedObject(embedUrl, accessToken, embedId, embedType, tokenType, dashboardId) {

    var models = window['powerbi-client'].models
    var permissions = models.Permissions.All;
    
    var config = {
        type: embedType,
        accessToken: accessToken,
        tokenType: tokenType,
        embedUrl: embedUrl,
        id: embedId,
        dashboardId: dashboardId,
        permissions: permissions,
        settings: {
            filterPaneEnabled: true,
            navContentPaneEnabled: true
        }
    };


    // Grab the reference to the div HTML element that will host the report.
    var embedContainer = document.getElementById('EmbedContainer');
    // Embed the report and display it within the div container.
    var embed = powerbi.embed(embedContainer, config);

    // Report.off removes a given event handler if it exists.
    embed.off("loaded");

    // Report.on will add an event handler which prints to Log window.

    embed.on("loaded", function () {
        window.external.LogToBrowserHost("Loaded");
        // Report.off removes a given event handler if it exists.

        embed.off("loaded");

    });

    embed.on("error", function (event) {
        window.external.LogToBrowserHost(event.detail);

        embed.off("error");
    });

    // Report.on will add an event handler which prints to Log window.

    embed.on("rendered", function () {
        window.external.LogToBrowserHost("Rendered");
        // Report.off removes a given event handler if it exists.
        embed.off("rendered");

    });

    embed.off("saved");
    embed.on("saved", function (event) {
        window.external.LogToBrowserHost(event.detail);
        if (event.detail.saveAs) {
            window.external.LogToBrowserHost('In order to interact with the new report, create a new token and load the new report');
        }
    });
    if (embedType === "tile") {
        embed.off("tileLoaded");
        //// Tile.on will add an event handler which prints to Log window.
        embed.on("tileLoaded", function (event) {
            window.external.LogToBrowserHost("Tile loaded event");
            window.external.LogToBrowserHost(JSON.stringify(event.detail));
        });
    };
    if (embedType === "dashboard" || embedType === "tile") {
        embed.off("tileClicked");
        embed.on("tileClicked", function (event) {
            window.external.LogToBrowserHost(JSON.stringify(event.detail));
        });
    };

};
```

**ReportLoader.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--To make this work we need to add The Mark-of-the-Web (MotW) Comment-->
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!-- Tell Browser control to use Document Mode IE11 See -- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/patricka/2015/01/12/controlling-webbrowser-control-compatibility/ -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <!-- Minified version of `es6-promise-auto` below. -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/es6-promise@4/dist/es6-promise.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/es6-promise@4/dist/es6-promise.auto.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js#startOpened,overrideConsole">
    </script>-->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/powerbi/powerbi.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/app/ReportLoader.js"></script>

    <style>
        html,
        body,
        div {
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="window.external.triggerDocumentComplete()">
    <div id="EmbedContainer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
     private void Embed_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     Uri uri = new Uri(@"pack://siteoforigin:,,,/html/ReportLoader.html");
     PBIEmbeddedWB.ObjectForScripting = new AddJavascriptObjects(EmbeddedLogger, PBIEmbedded_Invoke);
     PBIEmbeddedWB.Navigate(uri);
 }

[ComVisible(true)]
public class AddJavascriptObjects
{
    TextBlock logWindow = null;
    Action fireJavaScript = null;
    public AddJavascriptObjects(TextBlock logWindow,Action action)
    {
        this.logWindow = logWindow;
        this.fireJavaScript = action;
    }
    public void LogToBrowserHost(string message)
    {
        logWindow.Text = logWindow.Text + message + "\r\n";
        // Force logger to bottom of scroll
        var parentContainer = (ScrollViewer)logWindow.Parent;
        parentContainer.UpdateLayout();
        parentContainer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(parentContainer.ScrollableHeight);

    }
    public void triggerDocumentComplete()
    {
        fireJavaScript();
    }
}

public void PBIEmbedded_Invoke()
{
    PBIContentObject embed = null;
    object[] parameters = null;


    if (DashboardSelected.IsChecked.Value && appWorkSpacesDashboardList.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        embed = (PBIContentObject)appWorkSpacesDashboardList.SelectedItem;
        parameters = new object[] { embed.EmbeddedUrl, Token, embed.EmbeddedId, PBIObjectType.Dashboard, 0, string.Empty };
        PBIEmbeddedWB.InvokeScript("LoadEmbeddedObject", parameters);
    }
    else if (ReportSelected.IsChecked.Value && appWorkSpacesReportList.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        embed = (PBIContentObject)appWorkSpacesReportList.SelectedItem;
        parameters = new object[] { embed.EmbeddedUrl, Token, embed.EmbeddedId, PBIObjectType.Report, 0, string.Empty };
        PBIEmbeddedWB.InvokeScript("LoadEmbeddedObject", parameters);
    }
    else if (TileSelected.IsChecked.Value && appWorkSpacesDashboardList.SelectedItem != null & appWorkSpacesTileList.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        string dashboardId = ((PBIContentObject)appWorkSpacesDashboardList.SelectedItem).EmbeddedId;
        embed = (PBIContentObject)appWorkSpacesTileList.SelectedItem;
        parameters = new object[] { embed.EmbeddedUrl, Token, embed.EmbeddedId, PBIObjectType.Tile, 0, dashboardId };
        PBIEmbeddedWB.InvokeScript("LoadEmbeddedObject", parameters);
    }

}
```

I have tried this already
[WPF - Error while calling javascript function - Unknown name. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020006 (DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502898/wpf-error-while-calling-javascript-function-unknown-name-exception-from-hr)